# how to find root parents in tree using neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a tree, I would like to get all nodes at every level. The depth of tree could be anything.

```
node(1)<-[PARENT]-node(2)<-[PARENT]-node(3)<-[PARENT]-node(4)
node(1)<-[PARENT]-node(5)<-[PARENT]-node(6)
node(2)<-[PARENT]-node(7)
node(5)<-[PARENT]-node(8)
node(2)<-[PARENT]-node(9)
```

How to find root parent? (nodes who have no parents) please explain cypher query

Answer (score 3):

I would go with this:

```
MATCH (root)-[:PARENT]->()

WHERE NOT exists( ()-[:PARENT]->(root) )

RETURN root
```

If you want to allow isolated nodes, then go with this:

```
MATCH (root)-[:PARENT*0..1]->()

WHERE NOT exists( ()-[:PARENT]->(root) )

RETURN root
```

or even simpler:

```
MATCH (root)

WHERE NOT exists( ()-[:PARENT]->(root) )

RETURN root
```

but this might run afoul if you have other relationship types.

Answer (score 1):

The following will return all nodes that do not have an outgoing PARENT relationship. The `*0` syntax means that you want 0 PARENT relationships (that are outgoing, in this case).

This will match even an isolated node. But, be aware that this will also match all nodes that are not even in the tree (if you have any of those).

```
MATCH ()<-[:PARENT*0]-(p)
RETURN p;
```

If you also have non-tree nodes, you should give all tree nodes a label, say `Tnode`, in which case the query will be:

```
MATCH ()<-[:PARENT*0]-(p:Tnode)
RETURN p;
```

Comment: it not work this way, that one worked MATCH (d:DecisionNode) WHERE NOT (()-[:PARENT]->(d)) RETURN d